# Exact Target Data extensions and Fuel REST API

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am trying to send email and populate data extension using Triggered send REST API of exact target in salesforce to populate values in Data Extension using REST API.

I was able to send an batch sent email in salesforce using REST API.
I was able to populate attributes in data extension and printed in mail too.

But the challenge is
Each subscriber will receive a mail with his favourites data.

For example 
"X" likes Apple,Grape,Banana. 
"y" likes Grape,Mango.

I have 2 data extensions Transaction Extension and Favourites Extension. currently with no relation

In My mails X should receive a mail with he likes 
1.Apple
2. Grape 
3. Banana

What i want to know is 
How should I send these values as a JSON Payload in MessageSend.
How can we relate these two extensions.
what should be the ampscript in the mail.

Please Help someone.

more info

```
Transactions
Tid     Subscriber Email    first name
1           alpha@gmail.com         Alpha
2           beta@yahoo.com          Beta

Favourtes       
Favourtesid         Transaction id  Item Name
1                       1           Apple
2                       1           Orange
3                       1           Grape
4                       2           Apple
5                       2           Grape
```

Comment: Please try to select tags related to the subject of your question, this will help attract people with the right knowledge to your question! :)

Comment: Your use case flow is not making any sense to me, and making it difficult to provide an answer.  When does the data need to be entered? How are you populating any of the data currently? What is the purpose of the transaction ID, and how does it make it different.  I don't understand how all of the pieces work together. Can you supply any more code of what you are currently trying?  Not sure I'll be able to give a helpful answer otherwise.

Comment: In Our database we have Opportunity and Recommendations Object. Where Opportunity is Master and Recommendations is Child. ie Each Opportunity can have multiple Recommendations. The Scenario is My Agent Creates 3 Recommendations for an Opportunity today. By this a Trigger Send is invoked when all three are saved. Expected output is a mail with those three items. Next time Agent Creates 1 Recommendation for the same opportunity now the Mail should only get 1 new item. hope this give some information. Please let me know if i have to add more

Comment: How should I design this in terms of Data extension. and json payload.

Comment: Would you mind going here - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12838/exacttarget-architecture-review I would like to grant you access and we can continue this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `dataevents` by addingg `rowsets`.

Here is a sample call -

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:DataExtensionExternalKey/rowset
```

Add the header:

```
Authorization: Bearer gd2324hruukedkremtwqhae9
```

and the payload:

```
[
    {
        "keys":{
                "Email": "someone@exacttarget.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys": {
                "Email": "someone2@exacttarget.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can we attach This along with the Email json payload. or this has to be a seperate call

Comment: I would make sure that your data is updated prior to the email call. So yes, two calls.

Comment: My Transaction id is created only when my email is sent

Comment: Thanks, Kelly J Andrews. But i dont have 20 Reputation to chat.

Comment: I added you to the room.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use LookupRows function to get favorites data at "Favourtes" table.

The AMPScript will be something like below:

```
%%[ 
    VAR @Rows, @Tid, @currentrow, @row, @Item
    SET @Tid = Tid
    SET @Rows = LookupRows("Favourtes","Transaction id",@Tid)
]%%
%%[
    if ROWCOUNT(@Rows) > 0 then
]%%
    %%[
        for @currentrow = 1 to RowCount(@Rows) do
            SET @row = Row(@Rows, @currentrow)
            SET @Item Field(@row, "Item Name")
    ]%%
            <BR> %%=v(@item)=%%
    %%[
        next @currentrow
    ]%%
%%[ 
    else 
]%%
        <BR> No favourite data
%%[ 
    endif 
]%%
```

Take a look at the scenario presented at ExactTarget help:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/scenarios/

Comment: Thanks Lamotte, This should relly help us. also i wanted tje json structure for the payload in REST API if possible

Comment: {
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Tid": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks, How can we add favouries for each transaction. One Transaction can have many favourites